# Python Pandas: Convert DataFrame to dict and back

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a function that allows me to quickly convert a Dataframe to a text block from which I can quickly redo a DataFrame. This is to be able to post data along with my questions on SO in a quicker way :-) and also to be able to copy paste DataFrames between Jupyter Notebook. I am using the following logic:

[image]

However, as you can see, by doing that i receive the error `name 'Timestamp' is not defined` when I try to convert back to DataFrame. Any idea how to get past that error?

Comment: code should be posted as code

Comment: @e4c5 What do you want me to post sorry? My post is precisely about the fact that i have problem creating that very data...

Comment: you have posted code as an image code needs to be posted in plain text. Click edit and see the help section there please

Comment: @e4c5 This is obviously not plain text code but a webpage. Code is split into multiple cells. How am i supposed to reformat that into something that is readable? Anyway question answered.

Comment: Jim code is always text. whether it's in the console or a webpage http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Importing `Timestamp` properly should help:

```
from pandas import Timestamp
```

Alternatively you can:

```
import pandas as pd
```

and later use `Timestamp` with a qualified name:

```
pd.Timestamp
```

Please **don't**:

```
from pandas import *
```

This can lead to very hard to track bugs if do this for multiple libraries.
If two libraries use the name name, for example `write`, the one you import later would override the one you imported first.

Comment: ok thx, I was confused as obviously Pandas is imported already.I didnt know i have to redo the import a second time stating the exact function. WHy is it so?

Comment: hmm ok thx. I thought all the functions from the module would be imported properly without having to call them. Thx that's informative